# Filter Rectangles with 2:1 Aspect Ratio from an array of rectangles

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I have a rectangle array defined like this

```
Rectangle[] recArray = new Rectangle[100];
```

I need a way to filter out rectangles that have 1:2 aspect ratio like the one below

[image]

Please advice me the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a linq query like this:

```
var result = recArray.Where(x => x.Height / x.Width == 2).ToList();
```

The result is a `List<Rectangle>` which you can draw them or do whatever you need with them.

If you need an `Array` instead of the `List` use `.ToArray()` method instead of `ToList()`.

Also don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Thanks.. can i produce a new Rectangle array containing the Rectangles with this aspect ratio using LINQ.

Comment: If you need an `Array` instead of the `List` use `.ToArray()` method instead of `ToList()`.